# Why isn't this simple REGEX working?

Tags: javascript, regex

http://jsfiddle.net/C4K6c/

I'm trying to do a simple regex in JavaScript but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <p><img class="inline-image" src="1.jpg" data-frame="full" alt="" /></p>
    <p><img class="inline-image" src="2.jpg" data-frame="half" /></p>
    <p><img src="2.jpg" /></p>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML,
    matches = content.match(/<img(.+)data-frame(.+)>/);

for(var i=0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    alert( matches[i] )
}
```

I am not getting back what I am expecting, which is this:

```
<img class="inline-image" src="2.jpg" data-frame="half" />
<img class="inline-image" src="1.jpg" data-frame="full" alt="" />
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex when you could use, for example, querySelectorAll?

Comment: This regex `<img(.+)data-frame(.+)>` doesn't do wwhat you think it will do. It will match everything from the first `<img` up to the last `data-frame="">` it finds. Non-greedy will do the same up to the first `data-frame(.+)>` it finds. So if you have img's that don't contain `data-frame` you are going to get alot of junk. Html and regex really don't mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `g` flag and avoid the closing `>` to avoid having `</p>` in your match. And to avoid other problems if your HTML can be more diverse, you should also change the first `.+` :

```
matches = content.match(/<img([^>]+)data-frame([^>]+)>/g);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wc7Dt/)

Comment: About the closing: Use a non-greedy match: `/<img(.+)data-frame(.+?)>/` (instead of just a +, it is +?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it non-greedy and the DOTALL work-around:

```
matches = content.match(/<img([\s\S]+?)data-frame([^>]*)>/ig);
```

I also added `global` and `ignore case` switch.

Comment: Even non-greedy isin't much help when parsing html. In your case it still matches everything from `<img ` to several tags later `data-frame>`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/C4K6c/3/

As much as I love regex, I highly recommend using the DOM to your advantage here.

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var images = content.getElementsByTagName('img');
var final = [];
for (var i = 0; i< images.length; i++)
    if (images[i].hasAttribute("data-frame"))
        final.push(images[i]);
```

This algorithm has the advantage of being self documenting.  It's also probably faster than using a regular expression.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about java, but usually you need to escape the symbols < > like this:

```
matches = content.match(/\<img(.+)data-frame(.+)\>/);
```

Comment: That's not java but javascript, and you don't need to escape them.

Comment: @dystroy - Actually you do need to escape them if they are a literal that looks like a named group construct.